# After the function is done, sleep and print text

Tags: php

Hello, I have a question about PHP `sleep()`.

This is my source code:

```
if (function here) {
    functions.
    echo 'create ok';
}
sleep(10);

if (function here) {
    functions.
    echo 'Move Finished';
}
```

when I want to run this functions, the system sleeps for 10 seconds and after that shows:

```
create ok
Move Finished
```

But what I want is that when the function is done, show and print (create ok), after that sleep for 10 seconds and after that show and print (Move Finished).

What should I do?

Comment: Could you try to tidy up your pseudo code at least?

Comment: Please make your code readable. What does the two first lines of your code exactly do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using this code on a web page, you will need to flush the output buffer, i.e.

```
echo "create ok\n";
flush();
sleep(10);
echo "move finished\n";
```

See also: [`flush()`](http://php.net/flush)